# Difference between "partner and friend"

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-meaning

What is the difference between "partner" and "friend"?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Online dictionaries like the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) are actually quite good at helping you understand the differences between words.

Comment: Please share the definitions you’ve found, how you interpret them, and the context of the comparison.

Comment: Tell us which dictionaries you've consulted, and why they're so inadequate in explaining the meaning that you've decided to ask for our help.

Comment: This could actually be a very good question if you followed the pattern of "This is what I've learned already... and this is where I'm still confused." See Yoichi's ["Emperor vs King"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63039) question, e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partner can have many meanings, whereas friend normally refers to a specific interpersonal relationship.

Although different people may have different personal definitions of friendship, it usually does include that it is personal, private, it involves trust.

Partner can mean something similar, when you have a partner in a personal relationship: then partner can mean boy/girlfriend, life-partner, husband/wife, spouse or "significant other".

However, partner can also refer to a *professional* relationship. There has to be no personal "liking"or anything involved: people can be partners because they simply invest money in the same business for instance.

Comment: I just want to mention that Ice Girl and anyone else learning English should be very careful with the use of the word "partner." With no context, many people assume you mean "significant other" or "spouse;" partner is a common word used by gay and lesbian couples, especially "life partner." Therefore if you're not careful you may insinuate that someone you know strictly on a professional basis is your one true lover!